# How to keep all variables intact(the same) after a function call?

Tags: assembly, atmega, atmelstudio

I have written a simple assembly code that calculates the surface of a rectangle. However, all of my registers(including R0 and R1) have to stay the same after my function is called.

```
start:

.DEF var1= R16
.DEF var2= R17
.DEF suma2= R18
.DEF temp= R19
rjmp main2

Rectangle:
mov suma2, var1
mul suma2, var2
ret

main2:
ldi temp, low(RAMEND) 
out SPL, temp
ldi temp, high(RAMEND)
out SPH, temp

ldi var1, 3
ldi var2, 4
ldi suma2, 0

rcall Rectangle
rjmp end4

end4:
nop
```

This is the code I written. Does anybody by any chance know how I can improve my code so those registers will not change their value after the function is called? I am using Atmel Studio 7.0 and I am programming for ATmega8 microcontroller(and of course the code is written in assembly).

Comment: Save the registers on the stack.

Comment: Use call-preserved registers for stuff that you want to survive across a function call.  Most calling conventions have some call-clobbered (volatile), and some call-preserved (non-volatile) registers.  Of course you need to save/restore your own caller's values of those regs, but that can happen outside of any loops in your function.